# How can i divide my code using MVC pattern?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I need to create a simple like counter. My solution to this problem i wrote in class View. But I don't understand how can i divide my code into three parts - Model, View, Controller.

```
class View {
   constructor(model) {
            this.count = 0;
    
            this.renderInitialTodoForm();
    
            this.likeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                this.count++;
                this.likeCount.innerHTML = this.count;
            })
    
        }
    
        renderInitialTodoForm = () => {
            this.app = this.getElement('#root');
    
            this.likeButton = this.createElement('span');
            this.likeButton.textContent = '';
            this.likeButton.classList.add('like')
    
            this.likeCount = this.createElement('span');
            this.likeCount.textContent = 0;
    
    
            this.app.append(this.likeButton, this.likeCount);
        };
}
```

Comment: What would you say is the purpose of mode, view and conrtoller?
Why do you think this code must be changed to separated classes?

Comment: Is this an exercise to understand how MVC works? Here's a diagram: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller#/media/File:MVC-Process.svg

Comment: You might want to look up "Data access objects" for separating all the database access/query stuff from the model